# EF Core 6: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am migrating my project from `.Net 4.7` to `.Net 6`, so I have to migrate my `Entity Framework` too.

I have generate my first migration with `dotnet ef migrations add PortedToEFCore`. According to Microsoft, when we deal with existing database, we need to remove all the `Up()` and `Down()` from the added migration record from `dotnet ef migrations add`.

So here is my migration record `PortedToEFCore`:

```
public partial class PortedToEFCore : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

Then I have to modify some `relation table name` to match my old `.Net EF`.

This is my model:

```
public class Account : ObjectMapper
{
    [Key]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn("UserStore", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountProfile")]
    public Guid? AccountProfileId { get; set; }

    public AccountProfile AccountProfile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Store")]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn("UserStore", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid? StoreId { get; set; }
    public Store Store {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Access> Access { get; set; }
}

public class Access
{
    [Key]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string AccessName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class AccountProfile
{
    [Key]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Toolbelt.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.V5.IndexColumn(IsUnique = true)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

This code bellow is how I match my `relation table name`, the default relation table names are `AccountRole` and `AccessAccount` so this code is for matching the table name into `RoleAccounts` and `AccountAccesses`:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.BuildIndexesFromAnnotations();
        base.OnModelCreating(mb);

        mb.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany(left => left.Roles)
            .WithMany(right => right.Accounts)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "RoleAccounts",
        j => j
            .HasOne<Role>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("Role_ID"),
        j => j
            .HasOne<Account>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("Account_ID"));

        mb.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany(left => left.Access)
            .WithMany(right => right.Accounts)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "AccountAccesses",
        j => j
            .HasOne<Access>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("Access_ID"),
        j => j
            .HasOne<Account>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("Account_ID"));
    }
```

It can be compiled well, it runs. Then the problem is when I try to retrieve the record.

[image]

Notice here the `ADMIN` account has `NULL` `AccountProfileId` and `StoreId`. According to my model `Account` this is valid, but this error comes up everytime I try to access the `ADMIN` account:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method
> or property cannot be called on Null values.'

My example code:

```
var xxx = await db.Accounts.ToListAsync();
```

This code throws that error.

But if I create and connect a new `AccountProfile` and assign `StoreId` to `Admin` account. It can be retrieved alright.

What is this happening? My `Account` model specifies that `AccountProfileId` and `StoreId` are optional, why is this not working?

Comment: I expect that you have a required property somewhere which the database allows nulls. Maybe if you have enabled nullable reference types, your navigations should be nullable. Less likely, EF Core has defined a relationship by convention that shouldn't exist?

Comment: You could try creating a dummy database first project, add a migration, copy the database snapshot across to your project. Then create a new migration to detect any differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess, that non-nullable `AccountProfile` and `Store` cause this problem. Try to make them nullable to test my hypothesis.

That said, why are you describing migration in your question? You don't have a problem with it, do you? I have done similar conversion in a very different manner - but if you already have a model that matches the database, it probably doesn't matter. But your question is extremely confusing (to me at least) as to what exactly is the problem

Comment: To be honest I am super confuse migrating from < .Net 6 to .Net 6. All string were considered as nullable before, and now I have to specify hundreds of them in my code (not including all object references). It is working when I specify all of the problematic properties from Model and ViewModel into nullable. Thanks

Comment: yes; that's why I was asking about migration. if it's too late - so be it; but if not (similar to what @Jeremy Lakeman suggests) - scaffold the model (so, now you have equivalent between DB and Object model); and then create / apply migration (now you have clean migration without removing Up/Down). Then copy the data if you have to - and from there on - just update model and create migrations

Answer (score 0):

Since in .net version 6 and above nullable property is enabled by default, it is important to make all string variable in your model as nullable and set initial value as null. E.g. String? abc (? to make abc nullable) and String? abc = string.Empty to set the initial value.

Nullable property is defined in .csporj file of your project which can be removed, though it's not a good practice.